# can $4^{2n }$ be written as the sum of "three squares"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Lagrange theorem says only numbers $n \neq 4^n ( 8k+7)$ can be written as the sum of three squares.  what about this one?

$$  4= 2^2 + 0^2+ 0^2  $$

this looks acceptable to me, and yet it is excluded by Lagrange theorem.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: That's Legendre, not Lagrange.

Comment: If k = -1 then 4 (8k + 7) = -4.  Not 4.  If k = 1 then 4 (8k +7) = 60.  Not 4.  4 can not be written in such a form because 1 can not be written as 8k+7.

Comment: That way, ALL square is trivially a sum of $n$ squares for $n\gt 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *not* excluded; you cannot find $n$ and $k$ so that $4 = 4^n(8k + 7)$.

Comment: Good but with the "joker" $0$. I would at least have a case of $4^n$ as a sum of 3 nonzero squares.